# Python subprocess Popen not sending all arguments to shell

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

I am using Python's subprocess module to launch another program. The program requires an argument '-c{0-7}'.

```
this_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
cmd = [os.path.join(this_dir,'foobar'),'-c%d' % channel]
print "Starting process: %s" % str(cmd)
Proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True)
```

In the C++ program, I'm checking the arguments passed in:

```
for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
{   
    cerr << i << "   " << argv[i] << endl;
}   
cerr << "" << endl;
```

Here is the output when I run the python script:

```
user@home:~/embedded_pqa/saleae$ ./foobar.py -c3
Starting process: ['/home/user/code/foobar', '-c3']
0   /home/user/code/foobar
```

As is clear, the argument '-c3' is not being passed to the subprocess. Any thoughts?

Comment: A tool like `strace` or `truss` is the right thing to see what actually is or isn't being passed to the `execve` syscall. Also, `shell=True` is evil; if you want control of how your arguments are passed, don't use it.

Answer (score 12):

The issue is with `shell=True`. Quoting [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen):

> On Unix, with shell=True: […] If args is a sequence, the first item specifies the command string, and any additional items will be treated as additional arguments to the shell itself.

That means it calls the following command:

```
sh -c /home/user/code/foobar -c3
```

which the shell interprets as the command `/home/user/code/foobar` and an additional shell parameter `-c3`.

Just get rid of `shell=True` since you aren't using any sh features anyway and you're using an already separated argument list yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the help. `shell=True` was the culprit.